# Cordova UAP appx on Windows 10 crashes when app is min/maximized

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-10-universal, appx

Cordova UAP app on Windows 10 crashes when minimizing and maximizing it.

## Reproduce steps

1. Build cordova app using version 6.3.1 and windows engine version 4.4.3
2. Install the appx on Windows 10 (having store Version 11610.1001.23.0)
3. Open the app
4. Minimize and Maximize the app
5. Repeat *step 4* till on maximize the app crashes

## Exception

SCRIPT269: Unhandled exception at line 2126, column 9 in ms-appx-web://APP_IDENTIFIER/www/cordova.js

0x8001010d - JavaScript runtime error: An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call.

```js
function onResize() {
// Safely update the extended splash screen image coordinates. 
// This function will be fired in response to snapping, unsnapping, 
// rotation, etc... 
    if (splash) {
        // Update the coordinates of the splash screen image. 
        >>>> coordinates = splash.imageLocation; <<<< //this line causes the exception
        updateImageLocation(splash);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try it on a empty blank project?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT it happens on a empty cordova blank project too. Added in config.xml <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" /> and build the app --arch=x64. Important note: The app crashes only on the external monitor (via HDMI)

Comment: Have you tried on other device?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT when I plugin a VGA cable the app will not crash. I've also tested it on simular other laptops (same brand and  version) and on some I can reproduce and others not...